# Why `click()` fails on WebElement?

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor

I am using protractor with angular application. What I have in my page model is as follows:

```
export interface TileElement {
  idx: number;
  icon: string;
  title: string;
  element: WebElementPromise;
}
  getModels() { //used as wfc.getModels() below.
    return $$('mat-card').map((e, idx) => {
      // e.click();
      return {
        idx,
        icon: e.$('mat-card-content div:nth-child(1)').getText(),
        title: e.$('mat-card-content div:nth-child(2)').getText(),
        element: e.getWebElement()
      };
    }) as Promise<TileElement[]>;
  }
```

As you can see, I try to propagate `WebElement` to as part of the result so the caller can actually do something usefull with it later on - to click in my case. I use it like  this

```
await wfc.goToPage(); //works fine
const models = await wfc.getModels(); //works as expected - getModels from snippet above
console.log(await models[0].element.getId()); //prints some number eg 0.6760710380568453-1
console.log(await models[0].element.click()); //fails
//await $('mat-card').click(); this actually works
```

however, execution fails with exception

```
Failed: this.getId(...).then is not a function
TypeError: this.getId(...).then is not a function
    at WebElement.[serialize] (C:\workspaces\GDSR\gdsr-frontends\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1992:25)
    at convertValue (C:\workspaces\GDSR\gdsr-frontends\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:152:48)
    at C:\workspaces\GDSR\gdsr-frontends\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:187:17
    at forEachKey (C:\workspaces\GDSR\gdsr-frontends\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:177:9)
    at C:\workspaces\GDSR\gdsr-frontends\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:183:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at convertKeys (C:\workspaces\GDSR\gdsr-frontends\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:182:10)
    at convertValue (C:\workspaces\GDSR\gdsr-frontends\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:156:10)
    at toWireValue (C:\workspaces\GDSR\gdsr-frontends\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:128:26)
    at Driver.schedule (C:\workspaces\GDSR\gdsr-frontends\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:802:23)
```

As shown above, If I do `await $('mat-card').click();` it works as expected. If I do the `click` inside mapping callback, it will work as well.

The question is why it is not working with previously selected WebElement? I don't want to have to select elements before every action.

as a workaround, I am attaching `e.locator()` as a part of my interfacet, so during execution I am doing `await element(item.locator).click()` to make the click to happen, but this seems wrong.

Comment: what's your `wfc.getModels()`? and `models[0].element`

Comment: its in the first snippet.

Comment: Okay... I got that part now.. the last two confusions I need to clear out are: 1) `await $('mat-card').click(); it works as expected. If I do the click inside mapping callback, it will work as well.` sounds like both clicks work, yet the question is `Why click() fails on WebElement?` and 2) having in mind the title that the problem is actually with a click, I can see the error shows `this.getId(...).then is not a function` what am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing nothing, that exact error pops when I try to `await models[0].element.click()`. Previous line is a test to see if id exists, but it is a part of debug, not the main logic and can be ommited.

Comment: Long story short - I cannot `click` on `WebElement` returned in `map` function OUTSIDE of that function's execution scope. Its like WebElement beeing invalidated/detached from the driver context after mapping resolution. It might be by design, but I don't know that - and even so, it should throw meaningfull error in such case.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, what if you return just elementFinder

```
element: e
```

instead of

```
element: e.getWebElement()
```

Comment: Indeed I have tried that in the past and thios causes stackoverflow (lol) `Exception in PromiseRejectCallback:
C:\workspaces\GDSR\gdsr-frontends\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2123
  return new ctor(resolver);
         ^

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Exception in PromiseRejectCallback:
C:\workspaces\GDSR\gdsr-frontends\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1999
      fullyResolved(partialValue).then(`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `e.getWebElement()` to `element`, just pass `e` directly.

`getWebElement()` returns a `WebElement` of WebDriverJS instead of `ElementFinder` which is introduced by Protractor

Comment: Sergey had suggested that, and it raises stackoverflow for whatever reasons.